# How to scroll to top of UIPageViewController when status bar is pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a UIPageViewController that has a vertical orientation when it scrolls but it will not scroll to the top when the status bar is pressed. There are no other scroll views on the page if that helps.

Is there a scrolltotop function for a page view controller?

Comment: Can you post your code so we can see what you have tried so far?

Comment: This is essentially the code I have used...
http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIPageViewController as far as I know does not have any scrollToTop ability. To provide such a feature, I add an observer to listen status bar touch events. I use your appcoda link as reference project, so if you insert codes into related files, it'll work perfectly.

```
// AppDelegate.m
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"touchStatusBarClick" object:nil];
}

// ViewController.m

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    // add this line at the bottom of the function
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(statusBarTouched) name:@"touchStatusBarClick" object:nil];

}

// This function is called when status bar is touched
-(void) statusBarTouched
{
    PageContentViewController *startingViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *viewControllers = @[startingViewController];
    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionReverse animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

For easier implementation you can use this code in your childVC. This setting will make only visible ChildVC to be scrollsToTop-able.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
self.collectionView.scrollsToTop =NO;

}
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{    self.collectionView.scrollsToTop =YES;

}
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{

self.collectionView.scrollsToTop =NO;

}
```